# jQuery Ajax GET call does not refresh data on html page after success even though data variable shows correct values

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I use a value corresponding to a dropdown item and take a specific action in the controller depending on the value.  The controller function is called using jQuery ajax GET call.  The controller function correctly calculates and populates the list which is then retrieved in the View.  I have already verified that depending on the param value ( 0 , 1 or 2), the controller correctly populates the data in vm.SomeList. However, what is very puzzling is that once the controller calls the View, the code Model.SomeList has absolutely correct values.  However, the displayed data never changes and I have tried calling location.reload(true) even though I should not need to refresh the page to display the data.  I am perhaps not understanding how jQuery calls work.  I have researched this extensively and still cannot figure out the issue.  Especially, the viewmodel list parameter always has correct data depending on the option I select.  I can definitely make this work without ajax but now I am very curious.  Any pointers (including admonishments on not understanding basic jQuery) will be very welcome

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult FuncA(string param)
 {
        var vm = new SomeViewModel();
        ....
        ....

        try
        {
          
            // update a variable in view model...
            vm.someList = GetList(param);
          
            return View(vm);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
              // no exception thrown (I verified this)
        }
 }
```

View (.cshtml)

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.routed, "Routed to", new { @class = "col-sm-2 form-control"})

...

```
    @if (Model.SomeList.Any())
    {

        foreach (var item in Model.SomeList)
        {
            <tr>
            <!-- display the list items -->
            ...
            </tr>
        }
    }

</tbody>
```

jQuery Call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ...

        $('#filter').click(

            function () {
                alert("Reached 1");

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("FuncA", "Home")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {             
                            param: $('#routed').val()
                          },
                    dataType: 'text',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("Reached 2");
                        if (response != null) {
                            alert("Reached 3");
                            location.reload(true);

                        }
                        else {
                            alert("null response");
                        }
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error!")
                    }
                })
            }
        )

    });
```

Comment: I see in your Success that you reload the page. Maybe it's cached? Maybe set the location back to itself with some hash to ensure no caching. What do you see in console?

Comment: @Twisty With the suggested changes, here  I see the - Filter Click, Ajax Success and Ajax Payload not NULL calls.  This seems to indicate normal operation.  Still I dont see the updated data.  Now I also see that my Controller function is getting called twice!  One time with the value I selected from dropdown and second time with null value for param.

Comment: With Chrome, I believe I am seeing my dropdown value get changed back to default after click. I wonder if that is contributing to same data showing up. I will debug and then post again here.  Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$(function() {
  $('#filter').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Filter Click - Event Triggered.");
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("FuncA", "Home")',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        param: $('#routed').val()
      },
      dataType: 'text',
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("AJAX Success", response);
        if (response != null) {
          console.log("AJAX Payload Not NULL");
          location.href = location.href + "?" + Date.now();
        } else {
          console.log("AJAX Payload is empty.");
        }
      },
      error: function(x, e, t) {
        console.log("AJAX Error", e, t);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is a bit more cleaned up and should provide a lot more detail in the Console for testing.

Using the `click` event, we can use `.preventDefault()`. If it fails, nothing will happen. If it is successful, the page will be refreshed anyway.

```
location.reload(true);
```

This should work to reload the page and not cache. If it does not, try setting the location back to itself with some extra query.

```
location.href = location.href + "?" + Date.now();
```

This should ensure the browser does not load a cached version.